# Short story about an astronaut who writes to his partner on Earth and tries to warn her of her demise

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

This was a short story published before 2010, in the magazine Analog I think.

The premise was that a male astronaut sends messages to his female partner back on Earth. She writes to him too. But because of the nature of light travel he's essentially living in the future. He knows about Earth events a few years in advance. Because of this, all his messages are screened by the equivalent of NASA and any bits that may give away state secrets or reveal things about the future are taken out. The couple knew this was going to happen and joked about code words before they left, like "banana peel" would mean truck and "linoleum" would mean highway.

The story ends with his message to her to be careful of slipping on a banana peel on the linoleum on a certain date (except I don't remember specifically what code words the story actually used). We realize that he found out that she died in a car accident on that day and is trying to warn her.

Comment: Although it is very difficult to make a sensible theory of superluminal travel that does not permit time travel, it sounds to me like you are saying that the astronaut is travelling at subluminal speeds and somehow is sending messages to the past. Also, the fact that a theory permits time travel does not mean that it guarantees it along every path, depending on the nature of the theory. Further, there is nothing special about the astronaut: if the theory allows for superluminal communication, the earthbound partner can do the same thing.